# Using Variables Across Forms - VB

Tags: vb.net, radio-button, global-variables

I've got a fairly simple question (I think) on passing variables between forms using Visual Basic.

I've got a program with 2 forms (Form1 and Form2). Form1 has 3 radio buttons, which the user has to select one of and then loads Form2.

Now I've made it so that if radiobutton1 is picked, the Public Variable "radio_select" will equal "radiobutton1", if radiobutton2 is picked, "radio_select" will equal "radiobutton2".

But whenever I try call "radio_select" in my second form, it comes up blank. Why could this be? And how can I fix it.

I've tried using `if form1.radiobutton1.checked = true` but I keep getting the first radiobutton, regardless of the radio button I've selected.

I think the form is being unloaded, or there is an issue somewhere there, as it appears none of the variables get passed to the second form, once it has been initialized. Also note, the first form is hidden `Me.Hide()` when the second form is called.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered a slight re-design whereby you create a property on Form2 called RadioSelect and then set this from Form1 before showing Form2:

```
Class Form2
    Public Property RadioSelect As String
    ...
End Class

...

Dim f2 as new Form2()
f2.RadioSelect = "radiobutton2"

f2.Show() ' Or f2.ShowDialog()
```

This gets you away from an unnecessary public variable and should also ensure Form2 can see what it needs from Form1, or whoever calls it.

**Edit:**
The following works for me:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Test As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Test = "I'm Here"
        Me.Hide()
        Form2.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Text = Form1.Test
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hi David, your suggestion seems plausible, but I don't want to create Classes everytime I need a new variable passed between forms. Isn't there a simpler way to do this? Why doesn't just using `Public VariableName As String` Suffice? Why does it not retain its values?

Comment: Where is the public variable declared?

Comment: In Form1. Then I use Form1.VariableName to access it