# How to use the log in details from one form in another?

Tags: vb.net, forms, project, records

I'm creating a windows form application and I have made the sign up process so the users data is saved to a record. I have also got it so that when you go to sign in it search my records for a e-mail that is typed in and checks if the password matches. Now on the next form of the 'Signed In Page' I want to display the other information from that record on the page probably in a listbox. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSignIn.Click
    Dim RecordNumber As Integer
    Dim Found As Boolean
    Dim foundpword As Boolean
    Dim UserEmail As String
    Dim userPword As String
    Dim OneAccount As fmSignUp.SignUpInfo
    Dim stripeditem As String
    Dim strippword As String
    Dim CurrentUser As String

    UserEmail = tbEmailSignIn.Text
    userPword = tbPasswordSignIn.Text
    Found = False


    FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Random, , , Len(OneAccount))
    Do While (Not EOF(1)) And (Found = False)


        RecordNumber = RecordNumber + 1
        FileGet(1, OneAccount, RecordNumber)
        stripeditem = OneAccount.ContactEmail.Replace(" ", "")
        strippword = OneAccount.Password.Replace(" ", "")




        If stripeditem = UserEmail Then
            Found = True

        End If
        If strippword = userPword Then
            foundpword = True
        End If




    Loop
    FileClose(1)
```

This is where I declare the record.

```
   Dim OneAccount As fmSignUp.SignUpInfo
    filename = "AccountDetails.dat"
    FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Random, , , Len(OneAccount))
    NumberOfRecords = LOF(1) / Len(OneAccount)
    FileClose(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest is to crate a public method on current form
that returns a variable or a list of string that contains all information
you require from one form,
then in other form u can do:

```
Dim frm As Form1 = new Form1()
Dim tmp as string;
tmp = frm.ThatMethod()
```

See following as well:
[Using Variables Across Forms - VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253944/using-variables-across-forms-vb)